# css and js files are not loading using $this->load->view in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

This may be a duplicate question but I'm new in codeigniter. My question is whenever I tried `$this->load->view('anyhtmlpage.html')` it never loads the required css and js files.

**Condition:** All files in `view` must contain pure HTML (no php).

The base url is: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8081/SVN_propertybooking/branches/dev/Admin/';`

I also defined `$route['default_controller'] = 'Admin';` in `routes.php` and `$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url');` in `autoload.php`

And when I tried like this `<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` after `$this->load->view('anyhtmlpage.html')` it loads the css and js files.

But more amazing is when I write `header('location:'.base_url());` it loads all css and js files.

So what is missing here, help please.

**Folder structure:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load view should be

```
$this->load->view('anyhtmlpage'); # File name should be anyhtmlpage.php
```

and CSS will be

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As above code your css should place like this

```
application
assets
    - css
        - bootstrap.min.css
    - js
        - ab.js
    - images
        - no_image_found.png
system
index.php
```

Comment: but what if I require only pure html pages in my `view` folder

Comment: So no harm if you add `.php` as extension

Comment: sir this is the requirement, so can we make some adjustment (if possible). Else `.php` is the last option to me

Comment: @VilasGalave there is no any change in there. All what you have to do is just change extension to `.php`. this will works. Try once. Will wait for you on here. ok

Comment: ...it worked, thanks for taking efforts for me but my `PURE HTML` condition will never done. Thanks!

Comment: @VilasGalave happy to help :)

Comment: Best way to explain this answer!!specially folder structure

Comment: @Saty thanx buddy once again

Answer (score 1):

**In CI You can't load js and Css file using load->view**

you need to write direct in your template file or header file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**load url helper in controller**

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

You can check this tutorial for further help 
  :: [How to use css and js in CI](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-loading-css-and-javascript-file/)